# spring-social-github maven repository

Tags: spring, github-api, spring-social

I can't find Maven repository for [spring-social-github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-github/tree/master/spring-social-github). Could you please let me know where it is located ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spring Social](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/) is separated into different Projects which you can find if you follow the link above.

This is the [core](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social/core.html) module with the following maven dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

There is also [spring social facebook](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/) with the following maven dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

[Spring social twitter](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-twitter/) can be found here:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And so on.

If you want [Spring social github](http://projects.spring.io/spring-social-github/) you can go to the link before. Or grab this repository so that you will be able to add it to your project.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-github</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.M4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Spring will usually not make a public Maven repository available outside of their own repo. This means you have to add the repository above to be able to add Spring projects that are in a testing stage.

Here is an example pom.xml file with Spring social working:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-github</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.M4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Erick, thanks for your answer but I need Spring Social GitHub Maven repository

Comment: No problem. Added an example pom.xml as well.

Comment: Failed to collect dependencies at org.springframework.social:spring-social-github:jar:1.0.0.M4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.springframework.social:spring-social-github:jar:1.0.0.M4

Answer (score 0):

http://repo.spring.io/milestone

(admittedly taken from the other answer but it was well hidden there)

Bonus question: *why isn't it on maven central???*